# Select all checkboxes in all pages in the Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I need to select all the checkboxes of all pages according to the validation that I do, however the current validation only takes from the current page, and I needed that when clicking the button was selected and maintained of ALL pages even if I browse between them.

Example: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#issues/1167.html

I've already tried this:

Current JS :

```
Check: function (value, row, index) {
    var _this = oSelecao;

    if (row.check == true) {
        $('#btn_editarcep' + row.pfid).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#btn_editaremail' + row.pfid).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    if (row.cep.length != 8) {
        row.verificaEnder = 0;
    }
    if (row.verificaFotos == 0 || _this.ValidarEmail(row.email) == false || (_this.parampixel != "True" && (row.cep.length != 8 || row.verificaEnder == 0))) {
        if (_this.ValidarEmail(row.email) == false) {
            row.verificaEmail = 0;
        }
        return {
            disabled: true
        };
    }
    if (_this.Verificaseexiste(row)) {
        return {
            checked: true
        };
    }
    return value;
}
```

Tentative JS :

```
var allPages = oSelecao.fnGetNodes();

$('body').on('click', '#btnCheckMuniz', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) {
            $(row.check, allPages).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(row.check, allPages).prop('checked', true);
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('allChecked');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/3445#issuecomment-348382740

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="check">Check All</button>
     <button class="btn btn-default" id="uncheck">Uncheck All</button>
</div>
<table id="table"
       ...
       data-response-handler="responseHandler">
...

<script>
var checkAll = false

$(function () {
    $('#check').click(function () {
    checkAll = true
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('checkAll')
  })
    $('#uncheck').click(function () {
    checkAll = false
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('uncheckAll')
  })
})
function responseHandler(res) {
    res.rows.forEach(function (item) {
    item.state = checkAll
  })
  return res
}
</script>
```